# get_query_var don't working although it's in $wp->query_vars

Tags: wordpress

I try to use get_query_var for a new parameter "forumid".
I see the parameter when I print ($wp->query_vars),

> Array (
>       [forumid] => 23 )

But the get_query_var("forumid") return NULL

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse9870_query_vars' );
function wpse9870_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'forumid';

    return $query_vars;
}

add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpse9870_parse_request' );
function wpse9870_parse_request( &$wp )
{
    if ( array_key_exists( 'forumid', $wp->query_vars ) ) {
        echo get_query_var('forumid');
        require  'wp-content/plugins/forum/2.php';

        exit();
    }
    return;
}
```

In the file wp-content/plugins/forum/2.php I also get Null for get_query_var('forumid')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action hook `parse_request` is **to early**.

Read here -> [Action_Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)

The hook `parse_request` run's before `parse_query` where the query variables are just ben setted.

I think you should use `parse_query` instead of `parse_request`.

```
add_action( 'parse_query', 'wpse9870_parse_request' );
function wpse9870_parse_request( &$wp )
{
    if ( array_key_exists( 'forumid', $wp->query_vars ) ) {
        echo get_query_var('forumid');
        require  'wp-content/plugins/forum/2.php';

        exit();
    }
    return;
}
```